Creative Commons License (BY-SA) Violation: Data dump must not force users to agree to additional terms
The new mechanism for downloading the Data Dump appears to be be live. It still has a checkbox that requires acknowledgement of "additional terms" in addition to those included in the Creative Commons (CC BY-SA) license.

This is a clear violation of the BY-SA license, which states:

No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

A breach of the license terms results in automatic termination
From the Creative Commons FAQ:

All CC licenses are non-exclusive: creators and owners can enter into additional, different licensing arrangements for the same material at any time (often referred to as “dual-licensing” or “multi-licensing”). However, CC licenses are not revocable once granted unless there has been a breach, and even then the license is terminated only for the breaching licensee.

The company is requiring that I agree not to use the data in the file in a specific way, and levying consequences if I do. While the CC BY-SA license does allow gating access to covered creations, it does not allow additional restrictions on the use of the creative works. This checkbox is clearly intended to limit a specific use, in exchange for added consequences--this amounts to a violation of use.
As a content creator who has licensed my content to the world, including Stack Overflow, under the CC BY-SA license, and further recognizing that the Data Dump itself is explicitly licensed under tha same CC BY-SA license, the additional terms being added by Stack Overflow are a violation of that license.
How does Stack Overflow intend to remedy the situation?
I am requesting an official response from Staff, if that wasn't clear.

From a legal standpoint, that's not a license violation in that it doesn't actually impose additional terms. You're not required to agree to not use it for any particular purpose, you're just being told that the company doesn't want you to use it for particular purposes and that the company will be taking into account if you do/don't in their choices for their future actions and future dealings with you in ways they have every right to do. So, while I understand being upset about it, it's not actually a violation of the license.

You can read a bit more detailed discussion in "If an agreement puts some condition on a file, does the condition also apply to its content? (the content itself is under CC BY-SA)"

@Makyen -- My "lawyer-y people" (I call them lawyers, but I'm trying to speak the company's language) disagrees.  By requiring that I mark that checkbox, they are adding additional terms to the license.

@AMtwo Perhaps it would be beneficial for your lawyer-y people to talk to the company's lawyer-y people. But this wording is far less problematic than earlier drafts with respect since it no longer adds any restrictions to the license. It only influences if you have access to future works. If this wording isn't prohibited, then I don't see how any CC work could be anything other than made public and free. It would essentially block putting CC work behind a paywall, for example.

I think that there is another relevant part in the FAQS. Later they say "The use of any effective technical protection measures (such as digital rights management or “DRM”) by licensees to prevent others from exercising the licensed rights is prohibited." and is exactly what the company is doing., Furthermore, if you really want to go down the hard way on this, I may point out that this other issue also apply and Cesar fix there imho doesn't fly at all.

While they can certainly require a login, or otherwise gate access to the dumps, they are placing a restriction on how the data is used, and applying consequences for that specific use.  This amounts to an additional restriction, because they are restricting use, in addition to access.

@SPArcheon-onstrike There are no "effective technical protection measures" in place. We've been looking. As far as we've been able to tell, there is no watermarking or anything in the downloaded files that can be used to trace a file to the downloader. There's also no DRM or other security that prevents anyone from using it anyway they want to.

@Makyen I am hoping that it won't come to the need to involve lawyers. I am hoping that the company will engage/respond to my support request here.

@ThomasOwens not true. IMHO they would be perfectly fine to request you to pay 1$ contribute for the dump access, but they can't make you sign and handwaving of the rights the CC give you on the content in order to access the file. The fact that all they can do is blocking you from further access is not the issue.

@AMtwo There are no restrictions on how the data is used. For example, let's say that SE required registration to view site content. Would that be a CC BY-SA violation if they banned someone? No. I don't see how this is any different. If you break the terms of service, you lose access to future data. You can use the data you get anyway you want, though.

@SPArcheon-onstrike That's the thing, though. No rights are being taken away. Once you get a data dump, you can do anything you want with it. However, depending on what you do, that may be the last data dump you get.

@ThomasOwens The difference is that the conditions they put in place request you to give up some rights that the Creative Common license gives you. The fact that the only consequence of this "infringement" is a termination of your account and / or the ability to access the future dump is imho not part of the picture. That said, I don't care enough about my content here nor the site to want to start a bigger argument ... yet I can't hide that I am currently finding this mess quite entertaining.

@ThomasOwens You just described a restriction on how one uses the data. If you use it a certain way, there will be consequences. That's a use restriction. Period.

@SPArcheon-onstrike What right are you giving up? The answer is "none". If you download today's data dump, you can do everything that CC BY-SA says you can do. No one can take any action against you. The only thing you would lose is tomorrow's data dump, and that's permissable.

@AMtwo That is not what the CC licenses say. There are no restrictions on the data dump you download. There are restrictions on future data dumps.

...based on THE USE of the CC BY-SA licensed content that they provided.

@ThomasOwens you've made your point and I've made mine, and it appears you disagree, and that's cool. but lets cut it and give the company a chance to respond, k?

@ThomasOwens I agree to disagree. Not a lawyer, but I don't think they can put in place a condition that basically says "you won't make use of the rights described in the CC or we may terminate your account or something".

@AMtwo to be fair you also have the side option of contacting the Creative Commons organization directly and ask their opinion on the issue.

The quote from the CC license says "You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.". SE is not doing any of that. "If you do this I won't provide another nicely packaged copy" is "consequences", as you call it, but is not a legal restriction, which is what the CC license forbids.

This wording is not a violation of the CC BY-SA license.
There are no restrictions on how you use this file. That is, you can use it to train a large-language model if you want. If you do train a large-language model, SE cannot take action against you for violating the license. However, they can opt to not give you access to further data dumps.
CC BY-SA content can be gated. It can be behind a registration gate, a paywall, or anything else. The person distributing the content can choose who and how to distribute it.
The Creative Commons has a FAQ entry addressing this. The last paragraph of that section is particularly relevant. The terms of use are a separate contractual agreement and not part of the CC-licensed material. The terms of the CC-licensed material are not neutralized or changed, as they don't affect your use of the work. Nothing prohibits how you use the work from affecting future distributions, though.
Now, I don't agree that this is right. It's not within the spirit of the free and open-source nature of the content. Being open-source means not discriminating against users or fields of endeavor, which is what it is. However, this moves it into the space of ethical behavior and not legal behavior.

I am still wondering if it doesn't violate the other point mentioned in the CC Faqs. "The use of any effective technical protection measures (such as digital rights management or “DRM”) by licensees to prevent others from exercising the licensed rights is prohibited."

They are restricting my use of the data contained in the file by telling me that I cannot use the data dump to train an LLM. They can restrict distribution, but they cannot apply restrictions to how it is used.

@AMtwo They aren't restricting how you use it, though. You can train an LLM and there's nothing SE can do, except prevent future distribution of new works.

:blink: :blink:  "If you use this to train LLMs, there will be consequences" is definitely a restriction on use.  I'm really not sure how any reasonable person would think otherwise.

@AMtwo Because that's what the CC license says. It's quite clear. I'm not sure who you're getting advice from, but it's not consistent with most interpretations of the license. See the answers on Law Stack Exchange, too.

@AMtwo I've learned that what reasonable people think has very little to do with the law. This needs to be adjudicated to be resolved.

@AMtwo: Parsing the "I understand that this file" box is perhaps a bit subtle. Suppose the statement said instead "I understand Stack Overflow will punish me if I do things with the data dump they don't like". You're not agreeing not to do things Stack Overflow doesn't like, and you're not agreeing they have a right to punish you, you're just agreeing you've seen their warning.

I think, in spirit, this is pretty much exactly what a behemoth in free software world, now owned by a Titan of the software world, is doing with GPL- and other FOSS-licensed software. The behemoth is Red Hat, and the Titan is IBM. See this summary by the Software Freedom Conservancy from June 2023:

What Exactly Is the RHEL Business Model?
The most concise and pithy way to describe RHEL's business model is: “if you exercise your rights under the GPL, your money is no good here”. Specifically, IBM's Red Hat offers copies of RHEL to its customers, and each copy comes with a support and automatic-update subscription contract. As we understand it, this contract clearly states that the terms do not intend to contradict any rights to copy, modify, redistribute and/or reinstall the software as many times and as many places as the customer likes (see §1.4). Additionally, though, the contract indicates that if the customer engages in these activities, that Red Hat reserves the right to cancel that contract and make no further contracts with the customer for support and update services. In essence, Red Hat requires their customers to choose between (a) their software freedom and rights, and (b) remaining a Red Hat customer.

The post goes on to say:

Red Hat's lawyers clearly take the position that this business model complies with the GPL (though we aren't so sure), on grounds that that nothing in the GPL agreements requires an entity keep a business relationship with any other entity. They have further argued that such business relationships can be terminated based on any behaviors — including exercising rights guaranteed by the GPL agreements. Whether that analysis is correct is a matter of intense debate, and likely only a court case that disputed this particular issue would yield a definitive answer on whether that disagreeable behavior is permitted (or not) under the GPL agreements. Debates continue, even today, in copyleft expert circles, whether this model itself violates GPL. There is, however, no doubt that this provision is not in the spirit of the GPL agreements. The RHEL business model is unfriendly, captious, capricious, and cringe-worthy.

We could replace Red Hat with Stack Overflow and GPL with Creative Commons, and this entire paragraph would still be spot on - especially that last line. The rest of the post makes it clear Red Hat had been flirting with GPL violations for a long while before this.
But, like the SFC thinks is the case for Red Hat, I don't think we have enough to go on to claim Stack Overflow is violating CC BY-SA. For that, I think we will need Stack Overflow to actually impose a restriction, by, say, asking a person who received this data to not use it for LLM training. We don't have anything like that yet. Red Hat customers are unlikely to come forward, so the SFC is in a bind there. But if something like that actually happened with one of us, I'd bet that they would. If (or when) that happens, maybe we could even ask the SFC to take a look. Even if it is not entirely software, I think there would be enough code in the dumps for it to be of interest to them.

Well, the contact button there may end up in a nice article about this wonderful initiative.

Nobody forces additional terms, the data dump is just an alternative mechanism to access the same content as published on a website in a different format. Users who train LLM can still access the same content in traditional way, by loading web pages. There's no violation, because CC license does not imply obligation to deliver content in every format to every user. They can sell paper books with the same content and it would be normal right? So how requiring this checkmark is more problematic?

I don't think it's as straightforward as you state, because the ToS notes unequivocally that the dump itself is licensed under CC-BY-SA, which makes it very much possible for the company to violate those terms, i.e. by applying a meaningful supplemental agreement that competes with the standard license terms. You're absolutely correct that our content (e.g. posts on the site) is itself licensed, which isn't under the checkbox agreement, but I don't think that alone necessarily dismisses what's at issue here.

@zcoop98 well, if that is the issue, then the company can easily solve it by changing the Terms of Service...
